# How to set :autoclose option in Haml

Tags: ruby, haml, padrino, vxml

I am actually generating some xml from haml template, using Padrino Framework.
There are some tags that are self closing.
For that I did add following statement in subapp/app.rb as padrino is based on sinatra

```
set :haml, :autoclose => %w[meta img link br hr input area param col base else var assign script log submit exit reprompt goto]
```

But the Result is same for 
1. else tag 
I  get

```
<else> </else>
```

but expected is

```
<else />
```

Similar to br tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with in config/boot.rb

```
require 'haml/template/options'
Haml::Template.options[:autoclose] = %w[meta img link br hr input area param col base else var assign script log submit exit reprompt goto]
```

Comment: I added it in Padrino.after_load and gave following error:

uninitialized constant Haml::Template

Comment: yet the output is same as in the question

Answer (score 0):

It has to be [like this](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#options), if you're outside of Rails:

```
require 'haml/template/options'
Haml::Options.defaults[:format] = :xhtml
```